# Proving that $A$ being natural implies for UI martingale, $E([A,M]_\infty)=0$.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

The definition of natural process is

> $A$ is a finite variation process. It is natural if for every bounded martingale, we have $E([A,M]_\infty)=0$

In the proof of Girsanov-Meyer Theorem in Protter's Stochastic Integration and differential equation, the author applis this definition to uniform integrable martingale $M$.

So the question is how to prove:
$A$ being natural implies for UI martingale, $E([A,M]_\infty)=0$.

It seems UI martingale is not necessarily not locally bounded. If apply the fundamental theorem of local martingale, $M=N+D$ where $N$ is a local martingale with bounded jumps, $D$ is a finite variation process, then $N$ is locally bounded. However, it seems $E([A,D]_\infty)=0$ need not hold since $A,D$ may have the same point of discontinuity.

Does anyone have any comment or idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A possible way I can think of is the following: $A$ is predictable, by stopping we assume $A$ being bounded. By possible stopping, decompose $M=N+D$ where $N$ is a bounded martingale and $D$ is a $UI$ $FV$ martingale by fundamental theorem of local martingale. Then $E([A,N]_\infty)=0$ by the definition of natural.

For $E([A,D]_\infty)$, we observe
\begin{align*}
[A,D]_t=\sum_{s\leq t}\Delta A_s\Delta D_s
\end{align*}
Natural process is predictable. (Also, in the text $A$ is assumed to be predictable, so is $\Delta A$). We enumerate the these common jumps with increasing stopping time $T_i$ ($T_i\leq T_{i+1}$). Since the jumps of $A$ are accessible, we can WLOG assume $T_i$ are predictable.

\begin{align*}
E[A,D]_{T_i}= E[A,D]_{T_i^-}+E(\Delta A_{T_i}\Delta D_{T_i})
\end{align*}

By take the conditional expectation
\begin{align*}
E[E(\Delta A_{T_i}\Delta_{T_i}|\mathcal{F}_{T_i^-})]= E[\Delta A_{T_i}E[\Delta D_{T_i}|\mathcal{F}_{T_i^-}]]
\end{align*}
since $D$ is a UI martingale with $IV$, optional sampling implies $E[\Delta D_{T_i}|\mathcal{F}_{T_i^-}]=0$. Thus by induction $E[A,D]_{T_i}=0$ for all $i$. Consequently, let $i\rightarrow\infty$, $E[A,D]_\infty=0$ by dominated convergence theorem. (since $A$ is bounded, and $D$ is assumed to be $IV$.